# Why are the light not rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

The lights are the same on both models but it's not rendering the other one. Im trying to render in eevee.
Here's the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hn9aGMnDRiOCK2LCi9MmTNJLzxkpdzAh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Any help would be nice

Comment: Don't make the question depend exclusively on others downloading your file. Please [edit] your post and explain what you are doing and show images with your settings and project.

Answer (score 1):

You've hit the maximum lighting limit for Eevee.

The Blender manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html#limitations) states that

> - Only 128 active lights can be supported by Eevee in a scene.
> - Only 8 Shadowed sun lights can be supported at the same time.
> - As of now, lights can only have one colour and do not support light node trees.

I would suggest moving the duplicate ship over to a separate view layer, then combining the two using the compositor.